# What options do users have when we use Firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are thinking about using Firebase for authorization and are wondering which options does it give to the users when logged in to the app. For example, can they change email, deactivate the account, etc?

If you are using Firebase auth, please post a screenshot of the options your users have when managing their accounts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The options you can give users are based on the API provided by Firebase Authentication, since that defines exactly how you write your app code.  But you are not limited to that, since you can add as much extra information and functionality as you want by associating space in your database to the user account, using the account's unique ID.

No one screenshot will be able to demonstrate all possibilities.

I suggest looking through the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and [APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth) to better understand what the product can do.  A full summary is out of scope for a Stack Overflow answer.  In particular, I suggest reading about:

- [Signing in using a pre-built UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui)
- [Linking authentication providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)
- [Managing users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) in client-side code
- [Managing users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) in server-side code
- [Custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use with FirebaseUI Library]

1. Multiple Providers - sign-in flows for email/password, email link,
   phone authentication, Google Sign-In, Facebook Login, Twitter Login,
   and GitHub Login.
2. Account Management - flows to handle account management tasks, such
   as account creation and password resets.
3. Account Linking - flows to safely link user accounts across identity
   providers. Anonymous User Upgrading - flows to safely upgrade
   anonymous users.
4. Custom Themes - customize the look of FirebaseUI to match your app.
   Also, because FirebaseUI is open source, you can fork the project
   and customize it exactly to your needs.
5. Smart Lock for Passwords - automatic integration with Smart Lock for
   Passwords for fast cross-device sign-in.

**Dependencies**

dependencies {
    // ...

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'

// Required only if Facebook login support is required

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.x'

// Required only if Twitter login support is required

implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.x'
```

}